# Умножение строк в c#

Tags: c#

Можно ли реализовать умножение строк в c# как в Python ?

Например:  "string" * 5  и получаешь "stringstringstringstringstring"

Comment: `var s = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("string", 5));`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Если использовать `using System.Linq;` то:

```
string result = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("text" , 5));    
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Используя `using System.Text;`

```
string result = new StringBuilder().Insert(0, "string", 5).ToString();   
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Если подобное поведение нужно использовать часто, можно обернуть все это в метод расширения:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Repeat(this string value, int count) => string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(value, count));
}
```

И использовать вот так:

```
"string".Repeat(5);
```

Comment: @aepot а что не так с Join?))

Comment: Все с ним так. Просто Join нужен там, где надо между элементами коллекции что-то вставлять. Если вставка пустая, то и смысла в Join нет никакого. Я написал в причине правки, что это оптимизация, а не исправление.

Comment: жаль нельзя переопределить знак умножения